# ZFS when dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, zfs

I am currently dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10. I would like to try ZFS. Is it possible to use ZFS when dual booting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use ZFS on top of a partition just like other filesystems. When you create the zpool, just do:

```
zpool create <poolname> /dev/<path to partition>
```

I would not recommend creating multiple partitions, since it will not get you any particularly significant increase in redundancy if they’re all on the same disk.